# Deploying webapp using grunt on heroku not working

Tags: heroku, gruntjs, yeoman

I have added, grunt registerTask 'heroku' task to the Gruntfile.js file. But on doing git commit and git push heroku master, in the end I am getting this error. Kindly help me out here.

-----> Found Gruntfile, running grunt heroku:production task
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
 Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'
Warning: Task "heroku:production" not found. Use --force to continue.

```
grunt.registerTask('heroku',[
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'compass:dist', 
        'autoprefixer', 
        'concat',
        'imagemin',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'modernizr',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem yesterday.

You need to add `load-grunt-tasks` to your dependencies in package.json, not your devDependencies. Also, make sure your task is called `heroku:production`, as that is what the error clearly states.